# SQLite last_insert_rowid using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a problem using sqlite_last_insert_rowid in PHP.
CODE:

```
$database = new SQLiteDatabase('example.db');
$sql_1 = "INSERT INTO ex1(test1, test2) VALUES ('$test1','$test2')";
$database->queryExec($sql_1);

$ex1_ID = sqlite_last_insert_rowid($database);

$sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ex2 (ex1_ID, fname, lname) values ('$ex1_ID','$fname','$lname');";
$database->queryExec($sql);
```

I want to store ID from ex1 table to table ex2 in ex1_ID

```
CREATE TABLE ex1 ( 
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
test1 LONGTEXT,
test2 LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE ex2 ( 
ID INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
ex1_ID INTEGER,
fname LONGTEXT,
lname LONGTEXT,
FOREIGN KEY ( ex1_ID ) REFERENCES ex1 ( ID )
);
```

COMPLETE CODE:

```
$database = new SQLiteDatabase('example.db');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $test1 = "";
        $test2 = "";
        $lenght = rand(300, 400);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $lenght; $x++) {
            $test1 .= rand(0, 9);
            $test2 .= rand(0, 9);
        }
        $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO ex1 (test1,test2) VALUES ('$test1','$test2')";
        $database->queryExec($sql_1);
        $ex1_ID = sqlite_last_insert_rowid($database);

        for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
            for ($x = 0; $x < $lenght; $x++) {
                $test1 .= rand(0, 9);
                $test2 .= rand(0, 9);
            }
            $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ex2 (ex1_ID, fname, lname) values ('$ex1_ID','$test1','$test2');";
            $database->queryExec($sql_2);
        }
    }
```

I cant get the last ID from a ex1 table. 
Please help!

Comment: last_insert_id only applies for the current connection. if you haven't done any inserts in this session, there won't be a last_insert_id available.

Comment: Sorry my mistake in typing a code I change it. I try this code above and nothing I cant use ID from ex1 table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED now that we have more information.

Since you use an object-model way to query your DB, did you try

```
$lastid = $database->lastInsertRowid();
```

?

Comment: If you do an echo($ex1_ID)  what do you get?

Comment: Nothing its a blank page. I try echo and look for errors but nothing, In first table ex1 I have a stored ID = 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: And "$database->queryExec($sql_ex1);" (the ex1 insert) returns true or false?  Does data appear inside ex1 table?

Comment: Yes All data in table ex1 are stored and I have put the complete code above.